# Inconsistent spacing in quotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I've found something that looks like a small glitch in the new design. First, I didn't know that for quotations one could use either the markdown `>` or the html `<blockquote>`. But anyway, this is what they seem to produce

> This is some test quote using markdown.

> This is some test quote using html markup.

At least to my taste, the one above leaves too many whitespace bellow the quote, while the other one leaves too little. Maybe a more symmetrical alignment above and bellow would be preferable? Or is this intended by design?

Comment: it's a bug. I'll put in a fix for it tonight. thanks.

Comment: This can happen if the Markdown -> HTML converter assigns different CSS classes in the two cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this, it will be in the next deployment.